# Why do GDB and different assemblers give different and wrong jmp addresses?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, gdb

I wanted to run this assembly `jmp 0x8048540` in the C code (below) to run a function located at memory address 0x8048540. But I got seg fault. I decided to see where I went wrong...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define AMOUNT_OF_STUFF 10

//TODO: Ask IT why this is here
void win(){
    system("/bin/cat ./flag.txt");    
}


void vuln(){
    char * stuff = (char *)mmap(NULL, AMOUNT_OF_STUFF, PROT_EXEC|PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0, 0);
    if(stuff == MAP_FAILED){
        printf("Failed to get space. Please talk to admin\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("Give me %d bytes:\n", AMOUNT_OF_STUFF);
    fflush(stdout);
    int len = read(STDIN_FILENO, stuff, AMOUNT_OF_STUFF);
    if(len == 0){
        printf("You didn't give me anything :(");
        exit(0);
    }
    void (*func)() = (void (*)())stuff;
    func();      
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    printf("My mother told me to never accept things from strangers\n");
    printf("How bad could running a couple bytes be though?\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    vuln();
    return 0;
}
```

This is the function at the address:

```
Dump of assembler code for function win:
   0x08048540 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048541 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048543 <+3>: sub    $0x8,%esp
   0x08048546 <+6>: sub    $0xc,%esp
   0x08048549 <+9>: push   $0x8048700
   0x0804854e <+14>:    call   0x80483f0 <system@plt>
   0x08048553 <+19>:    add    $0x10,%esp
   0x08048556 <+22>:    leave  
   0x08048557 <+23>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

I noticed that the opcode that my assemblers gave me were inconsistent. The jump addresses they gave me were also different from the intended address of 0x8048540.

According to defuse.ca for x86, my string literal is `\xE9\x3C\x85\x04\x08`. The address I see is 0x804853C

However, according to rasm2 for x86, my string literal is `\xe9\x3b\x85\x04\x08`. The address I see is 0x804853B

1st Qn: Why are the addresses different from my intended address and so different from each other? They were both supposed to give opcode for x86.

Nevertheless, I just decided to go with rasm2's opcode.
Then, I noticed something weird in GDB. (Note: the read() command reads 10 bytes to the memory address 0xf7fd3000.

```
(gdb) x/8x 0xf7fd3000
0xf7fd3000: 0xe9    0x3b    0x85    0x04    0x08    0x00    0x00    0x00
```

Seems all well and good so far. The value in the memory address matches the string literal given by rasm2. 
Then I decided to see the memory in terms of instructions:

```
(gdb) x/2i 0xf7fd3000
   0xf7fd3000:  jmp    0x1b540
   0xf7fd3005:  add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
```

Woah. Why jump to address 0x1b540?? Could it just be a visual error? 
So I ran it.

But GDB REALLY jumped to that address!

```
(gdb) si
0x0001b540 in ?? ()
=> 0x0001b540:  Cannot access memory at address 0x1b540
```

I thought perhaps I made a mistake. Perhaps `jmp 0x8048540` is illegal. But, according to [this source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JMP_(x86_instruction)), jmp accepts 32 bit pointers.

2nd Qn: Why is GDB giving me such a ridiculous address?

Could someone kindly enlighten me the reason behind the different addresses? All I want is just to jump to 0x8048540. defuse.ca gave me 0x804853C, rasm2 gave me 0x804853B, and GDB gave me 0x1b540. T.T

Thank you.

FYI, this is from Shells challenge in PicoCTF 2017.

Comment: `void (*func)() = (void (*)())stuff;` look suspicious.

Comment: That makes the input executable. The machine code for "jmp 0x8048540" is the input. It gets run to run the function at 0x8048540. At least that's how I intend it to be. I honestly dont think that line of code is the problem.

Comment: this line is weird because cast pointer always show something wrong in your design. Here you could easily avoid the cast. Next problem`int len = read(STDIN_FILENO, stuff, AMOUNT_OF_STUFF);
    if(len == 0){` => `ssize_t len = read(STDIN_FILENO, stuff, AMOUNT_OF_STUFF);
    if(len != AMOUNT_OF_STUFF){`

Comment: I don't understand what is your point, whatever the result is good or not, arbitrary jmp in memory would probably result to a segmentation fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The machine code for "`jmp 0x8048540`" is the input.

That's wrong:

There are different kinds of `jmp` instructions (like `jmp ecx` which takes the destination address from the `ecx` register) on x86 CPUs.

The jump instructions (`jmp`, `call`, `je`, `jae` ...) which take an immediate value however are PC-relative:

The destination address of the jump is calculated by the formula:

```
argument of "jmp" + address of the next instruction
```

So the following code:

```
0x12340000 E9 00 00 01 00
```

Disassembles to:

```
0x12340000 jmp 0x12350005
```

This is calculated the following way:

- The `jmp` instruction is 5 bytes long and it is located at address 0x12340000. So the next instruction (the instruction following `jmp`) is located at 0x12340005.
- The argument of `jmp` is 0x10000 and 0x12340005 + 0x10000 = 0x12350005.

And of course: The instruction will not only disassemble like this but also jump to 0x12350005.

Comment: wait, where does the 5 come from? Do you mean that to be `0x12340005 E9 00 00 01 00` and `0x12340005 jmp 0x12350005`?

Comment: @yano No: The instruction is located at 0x12340000 and the `jmp` instruction is 5 bytes long. So the **next** instruction (the instruction following the `jmp` instruction) is located at 0x12340005.